# Accessing my Windows D:Drive, using Ubuntu 16

Tags: partitioning, windows, hard-drive, windows-7, external-hdd

I really need some help here. I am a little out of my depth using Ubuntu, so am finding my way.

So, here goes.

I have a laptop that I have only ever run Windows 7 on. This laptop is seriously broken. Windows will not boot up.

So, on the advice of a friend, I am trying to use Ubuntu.

My objective is to copy my photos and music off the D:Drive and onto an external hard drive.

So far so good.

So, I have used Ubuntu 16.04.2 to boot my computer via a USB stick. I have used the "Try" option as I was worried about making changes to the hard drive.

Ubuntu has loaded, by I cannot see any documents or files as all. So here is my question:

In simple terms, how do I access my old Windows C: and D: drives? Then how do I copy them to my external hard drive?

If you take the time to reply, thank you. But please imagine you are talking six year old, if you offer advice.

Answer (score 3):

**This answer assumes that the drives on your laptop are not damaged**

Boot the computer using the live USB and select Try Ubuntu.

Click the file drawer icon on the left side of the screen.  You will see a window similar to this.

[image]

On the left of the new window you will need to locate the drive where your windows files are located.  On this example screen there is a drive called "322 GB Volume".  Depending on how your laptop is set up, there may be several choices.

Click on the volume(s) of interest to mount them.  Their contents will be displayed in the window.  Find the files you wish to save.

Plug in the USB drive you wish to save the data to.  If it does not automount, mount it by clicking on it in the left column as well.

Copy (drag, or select and copy) the files you wish to keep to the USB storage device.

Comment: Hi @Organic Marble. Thanks for taking the time to reply. I appreciate it. I think we have found our problem.... On my computer I cannot see a drive on the left hand menu. Al I have is "Computer" and "Connect to Network." What does this mean? Am I in trouble? Any ideas?

Comment: That sounds like your laptop drives are not showing up.  I don't think all is lost, but you will probably have to get into command line territory.